# FluentWait ignore not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium WebDriver test that is failing after dismissing a modal window then waiting for an element.  Specifically, it fails looking for an element in a `FluentWait` call.  I've tried various different ways of setting up the wait, but none are working.  Here is what I think should work:

The test code that is failing:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("dismiss")).click(); // this dismisses a modal window
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.className("next"))));

driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click();
```

Here the failure happens looking for the element in the wait call:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"class name","selector":"next"} Command duration or timeout:
>   1.33 seconds For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
>   System info: host: '7rzrgv1.bsolver.local', ip: '10.0.3.103', os.name:
>   'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_60' Session ID:
>   56c5a752-68fd-4cdb-ae57-2fcefc930f6f Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true, version=24.6.0}]

If I replace the `fluentWait.until` call with a `Thread.sleep(5000)`, the `click()` works every time.

An interesting note... this only occurs when running the test on a headless machine running Firefox on top of Xvfb.  It doesn't occur when an actual GUI is present.

So, a couple of questions:

Why is `FluentWait` not ignoring the `NoSuchElementException` ?

Does anyone have thoughts on a more elegant way to deal with this other than an implicit wait?

Comment: Can you show your imports? I guess you are using `NoSuchElementException` from some other package.

Comment: Just checked my imports, I'm importing `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. @Karna and @Axl helped me figure it out. I was using `import java.util.NoSuchElementException;` instead of `import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;`.